# Gotchas of JavaScript's Number type (C's double)

Tags: javascript, floating-point

What are some important considerations for developers using JavaScript's Number type? I know it's an implementation of C's `double` type, but I'm a self-taught Python developer so that doesn't take me very far.
Pointers to well-written articles will be great answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's just the general problems that plague Floating Point based arithmetic.  For example, .1 + .2 == 0.30000000000000004 in JavaScript.

A good article on floating point arithmetic in general, and some of the problems associated with it can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) on Wikipedia.

---

Edit: a previous answer to a similar question that seemed to be pretty popular - [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken/588014#588014)